# cc1.exe-entry point not found

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks

cc1.exe - entry point not found
The procedure entry point__divmoddi4 could not be located in the dynamic link library
c:\mingw\bin..\libexec\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\cc1.exe.

I have no idea what to do for this kind. I used windows 10.

Comment: I believe you have older dlls with the same name in your PATH. These are found before the newer dll.

Comment: Please explain what you are attempting, and what is going wrong, otherwise the exact problem you are facing can be quite difficult to solve.